# How do I create a link to a file I have saved as a memory stream in a SQL table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

My web application (C# and ASP.Net) allows someone to upload a jpg/pdf file and save it as a memory stream inside a SQL table. This is what it looks like once written in the table:

```
0xFFD8FFE000104A4649.....
```

Now I want to provide this file back on my web interface through a link where the user can download this file. I have retrieved my file by converting the string above back to a byte array using

```
filedata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(<string above>);
```

Then I called this:

```
string filename = "pic.jpg";
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, filedata);
```

But I have no clue how I should post this back to the user as a downloadable link on my web interface. Do I have to save this file to a temporary folder on my server or is there a way that I could invoke a call to render my file back as a picture where the user will be prompted to save the file or open it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to create a page / action / function that writes the bits back as the response to an HTTP request.  Keep in mind that in doing so you will probably need to set the proper `Content-Type` header in the response according to what your file is.

So, you generate a link that calls your page / action / function.  Then That sends the binary data back in an HTTP response.  Something like

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/getFile.aspx?fileName=pic.jpg">pic.jpg</a>
```

If you some detail as to what framework you're using (MVC, WebForms, etc) then we can give more detailed examples.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using WebForms

Comment: Ah ok I see, so the extra page takes care of handling when the http response, and when the session is killed. I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, precisely.  The extra page generates a response and the content of that response is your file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to present the image.

If you want to embed the image in the web return an link to the file with

```
string filename = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Content/Images/pic.jpg");
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, filedata);
return filename;
```

then in the JavaScript side create an `img` element with that`src`

Or if you want the user to download the file do what @squillman says in his answer

Comment: This would work also, and is easier than my answer.  ASP.NET has to have write permissions to your filesystem.  And you would probably also want to add something to clean up the file after it's been sent back to the client.